# Android : Finding the distance between User's Current Location and a beacon

Tags: android, beacon, eddystone

I am trying to find the distance between a Eddy Stone Beacon and User's current in Android device.
What i did so far is, I have written code to detect the nearest beacon and it worked.To proceed further i need some suggestion that how can I achieve this.
Using Some formula?  To use Maps ? Please provide what can i exactly do..

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.estimote.sdk.Beacon;
import com.estimote.sdk.BeaconManager;
import com.estimote.sdk.Region;
import com.estimote.sdk.SystemRequirementsChecker;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private BeaconManager mBeaconManager;
private Region mRegion;


@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mBeaconManager = new BeaconManager(this);

    mBeaconManager.setRangingListener(new BeaconManager.RangingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBeaconsDiscovered(Region region, List<Beacon> list) {

            if (!list.isEmpty()) {


                Log.d(TAG, "onBeaconsDiscovered: " + list.size());
                Beacon nearestBeacon = list.get(0);
                Log.d(TAG, "UUID: " + nearestBeacon.getProximityUUID());

                Log.d(TAG, "Strength: " + nearestBeacon.getRssi());
            }
        }
    });
    mRegion = new Region("Ranged Region", null, null, null);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SystemRequirementsChecker.checkWithDefaultDialogs(this);
    mBeaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceReady() {
            mBeaconManager.startRanging(mRegion);
        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    mBeaconManager.stopRanging(mRegion);
    super.onPause();

}
```

}

**Edited MainActivity**

```
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mBeaconManager = new BeaconManager(this);

    mBeaconManager.setRangingListener(new BeaconManager.RangingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBeaconsDiscovered(Region region, List<Beacon> list) {

            if (!list.isEmpty()) {


                Log.d(TAG, "onBeaconsDiscovered: " + list.size());
                Beacon nearestBeacon = list.get(0);

                UUID beaconId = nearestBeacon.getProximityUUID();
                int strength = nearestBeacon.getRssi();
                int minNumber = nearestBeacon.getMinor();
                int majorNumber = nearestBeacon.getMajor();
                int txPower = nearestBeacon.getMeasuredPower();

                Log.d(TAG, "UUID: " + nearestBeacon.getProximityUUID());
                Log.d(TAG, "Strength: " + nearestBeacon.getRssi());

                Log.d(TAG, "MinNum " + nearestBeacon.getMinor());
                Log.d(TAG, "MaxNum: " + nearestBeacon.getMajor());
                Log.d(TAG, "Tx: " + nearestBeacon.getMeasuredPower());

                double distance;

                if (strength == 0) {
                    distance = -1.0; 
                    Log.d(TAG, "dis1: " + distance);
                }

                double ratio = strength * 1.0 / txPower;
                if (ratio < 1.0) {
                    distance = Math.pow(ratio, 10);
                    Log.d(TAG, "dis2: " + distance);

                } else {
                    double accuracy = (0.89976) * Math.pow(ratio, 7.7095) + 
                     0.111;
                    distance = accuracy;
                    Log.d(TAG, "dis3: " + distance);

                }


            }
        }
    });

    mRegion = new Region("Ranged Region", null, null, null);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SystemRequirementsChecker.checkWithDefaultDialogs(this);
    mBeaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceReady() {
            mBeaconManager.startRanging(mRegion);
        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    mBeaconManager.stopRanging(mRegion);
    super.onPause();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The Estimote API provides a [Utils.computeAccuracy](https://estimote.github.io/Android-SDK/JavaDocs/com/estimote/sdk/Utils.html#computeAccuracy-com.estimote.sdk.Beacon-) method to compute distance to the beacon. In version 1.0.0 of the API, this utils moved to [RegionUtils.computeAccuracy](https://estimote.github.io/Android-SDK/JavaDocs/com/estimote/coresdk/observation/region/RegionUtils.html#computeProximity-com.estimote.coresdk.recognition.packets.Beacon-)

```
mBeaconManager.setRangingListener(new BeaconManager.RangingListener() {
    @Override
    public void onBeaconsDiscovered(Region region, List<Beacon> list) {
        if (!list.isEmpty()) {
            Beacon nearestBeacon = list.get(0);
            double distance = com.estimote.sdk.Utils.computeAccuracy(nearestBeacon);
        }
    }
});
```

I believe this is calculated based on signal theory by comparing received signal strength and expected signal strength transmitted in data packet. The lower signal received the more far from the beacon. As @davidgyoung mentioned, this is just rough distance estimation. Different devices (phones and beacons) models will have little different radios and thus different measurements. Also the environment between phone and beacon make differences. I recommend this article to understand: https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/distance-calculations.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now that i have found the distance but with the hardcoded best fit curve value. Please look on to my edit. How to calculate/ get the best fit curve value. Any help would be really useful.